# How to download file from google drive using c#

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I can't download file from google drive using below mentioned code

```
string url = https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXX
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credential = new NetworkCredential("XXXX","XXXX");
client.DownloadFile(url,@"D:\\test.xls");
```

Could you please suggest me to how to download the file using webclient with user credential?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet is not an option for some reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download file from google drive using below mentioned Link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728116/How-to-download-a-file-from-Google-Drive-in-csharp

Comment: The tricky part seems to be creating the credentials for accessing the API.  If I want to download a spreadsheet in my drive I probably want to use the Drive API.  Not sure if I need to setup creds for App Data or User Data.

Comment: Hello @fireydude, Can we download files without creating credentials from google console?

Comment: I would guess not

Answer (score 0):

There is a Quickstart guide for .NET developers in the Drive API docs.

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

In theory this should work however I am not convinced .NET is well supported.  It might be a good idea to try the javascript guide and see how it compares.